# HTML Images rendered with delay in mobile Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

I have a website that consists mostly of images, which are either set as background to divs or as .

Problem is that on every phone I have checked, when scrolling the site top to bottom and vice-versa images are rendered slowly. Sometimes they remain rendered, other times they get re-drawn.

It's not that the images are not loaded, as they get displayed at some point of time, but after a few seconds when swiping back to them, they disappear and appear when scrolling back to them.

I've checked with all Samsung Galaxy lineup, including tablets and this behavior is the same.

Preloading the images seems to have absolutely no effect, and the same behavior appears whether the image resolution is high or low.

Is there any way to force Chrome not to redraw images randomly?